# Android Oreo JobIntentService Keep running in background for Android 7 &below and crashing often in Android 8 & above

Tags: android, intentservice, jobintentservice

I have recently replaced all my service to foreground services and JobIntentService since there are some background execution limits (https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background) in oreo and above. As per documentation, JobIntentService acts like Intent Service for Android 7 & below and acts like JobScheduler for Android 8 & above. I have noticed there is an issue in new JobIntentService provided by Google.

**Android 8 & above:**

There is a crash happening continuously in android 8 and above. There was a ticket raised here mentioning about the same issue https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63622293 and I have added a temp fix suggested by few geeks.

**Android 7 & below:**
JobIntentService which acts like Intent Service is not getting stopped once the work is done.

I have implemented JobIntentService within a service which triggers whenever some action is performed by a user.

**Code**

```
public class SampleJobIntentService extends FixedJobIntentService {

public static void postData(Context context, String data) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, SampleJobIntentService.class);
            intent.setAction(INITIAL_ACTION);
            intent.putExtra(SAMPLE_ID, data);
            SampleJobIntentService.enqueueWork(context,intent);
}

public static void enqueueWork(Context context, Intent work) {
    SampleJobIntentService.enqueueWork(context, SampleJobIntentService.class, JOB_ID, work);

 @Override
    protected void onHandleWork(@NonNull Intent intent) {
        if (intent != null) {
            SampleRequest sampleRequest = requests.get(intent.getAction());
            if (sampleRequest != null) {
                try {
                   // perform some networking operations
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Log.d("Error for intent ");
                }
                Log.i("send action ");
            } else
                Log.e("action not found for ");
        }
    }
    }
```

To avoid the crash with JobIntentService, I took few references from https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63622293

```
public abstract class FixedJobIntentService extends JobIntentService {

    @Override
    GenericWorkItem dequeueWork() {
        try {
            return new FixedGenericWorkItem(super.dequeueWork());
        } catch (SecurityException ignored) {
            doStopCurrentWork();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private class FixedGenericWorkItem implements GenericWorkItem {
        final GenericWorkItem mGenericWorkItem;

        FixedGenericWorkItem(GenericWorkItem genericWorkItem) {
            mGenericWorkItem = genericWorkItem;
        }

        @Override
        public Intent getIntent() {
            if (mGenericWorkItem != null) {
                return mGenericWorkItem.getIntent();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void complete() {
            try {
                if (mGenericWorkItem != null) {
                    mGenericWorkItem.complete();
                }
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException ignored) {
                doStopCurrentWork();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are u triggering a service to trigger a JobIntentService. JobIntentService can be triggered directly on user action ?

Comment: @Ankur Even if I trigger JobIntentService directly, it is not getting killed once the work is done. I have mentioned one scenario where it is used in my project. I have a couple of JobIntentServices used in my project

Comment: Can u provide with the sample code of JobIntentService which you are using with the trigger code ?

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: @Kalai.G, Okay... I got it... I am explaining it step by step as answer ... as i don't see much space left here... and i do not want to make complete thread full of like chit chat.

Comment: whoever downvoted the question please give me a valid reason. Do you think developers reported here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63622293 were dump?

Answer (score 19):

> Well..., Its a lot big theory...!! It would not be able to put it all here. I will try my best which will make some your concepts clear.

---

I have already lost my 2 complete years in reading google documentations... Which are `use-less`... With `no proper documentation` and with `no proper sample codes for its developers`..!! So i mention this in every of my posts on `stack-overflow`, As it will help to save time of others..!!

---

It looks you are a good programmer; just need some `hints to your posted question` :

**Hint-1 :**

> YOU :- I have recently replaced all my service to foreground services and
>   JobIntentService

**foreground service :**

If you need `ALL THE TIME RUNNING PROCESS; WHICH WILL NEVER END... ONCE IT IS STARTED` it is used in service which returns `START_STICKY` from its `OnStartCommand`. Which is again not advised to use as if you want to implement it at any cost ... then you will have to use a notification with `setOngoing(true)` Which end user would not be able to swipe away your notification, it will remain there forever....

**Use of the foreground service :**

There has been restrictions on receivers too; above `Oreo` onwards and you can not use all the receivers and intent actions by declaring it in manifest and by just making a receiver... I advice to just use `BootComplete` permission and use a single `receiver` which receives the `boot_completed` intent and calls a `service` if below O and calls a foreground service above O. Now from that foreground service you implement the runtime receivers for all and unregister it in Ondestroy methods. I have never found an official sample code for implementing runtime receiver and finally i have implemented it successfully by many months hard-work... Yes it was not a smart work due to google

**When to use foreground service :**

Only if you want to implement broadcast receivers.... If you do not want to implement any broadcast receivers; STAY AWAY.......

**Hint-2 :**

> YOU :- I have recently replaced all my service to foreground services and
>   `JobIntentService`

** service has its quality of :**

Just doing a very tiny work... and just exit... it has to be exited by S`topSelf()`... Again, `Services can cause data-loss` if called multiple times... As same service thread can be run more than once...  Again if you want a service to do a lot of work... Use `START_STICKY`... But again it is not recommended and i have suggested already, when to use it in Hint 1.

** Intentservice has its quality of :**

Doing a relatively long running tasks and it has `property of execution serially only` If you again and again calls the same `intentService`, then all calls will be kept in a `queue` and will be executed `one by one` after finishing `one by one`. Which is not the case in service as depicted above. It ends on its own... no need to end it by a developer..!!

** Unique Quality of all :**

Once they are `crashed` android can stop them calling in future without notifying you as it crashes the app. Need to be handled them with `try-catch-exception` to `avoid crash`. Again... If `you are implementing threads within services` then `try-catch-exception` `will not save your application from being crashing`...

** THEN WHAT THE HELL & HOW TO IMPLEMENT IT THEN :**

Use `FireBaseJobScedular` :-

1. Easy to use
2. Uses simple JobService
3. Can run longer or smaller time tasks... `EVEN ALL THE TIME RUNNING TASK`
4. `EVEN SUPPORTED BY NON STANDARD COMPANIES` like vivo, mi, oppo, one+3, ... which takes `stock-android` makes changes to it and gives names like FunTouchOs, ColorOs, OxygenOs
5. Just need to Do change battery settings to "Do not optimise this app"
6. Yes google supports it officially and recommends to use it
7. It Creates the instance of `GooglePlyService` and runs within it, And obviously non-standards companies too would not restrict google apps from being doing its tasks.
8. Works on `Oreo` .., Even i have tested it on `Android P` and works below Android version 5.0 as `AlarmManager` tasks.
9. Still i recommends to use `minsdk above 16`, `target sdk 26` as if in case you wants to upload your app to `google play` it is compulsory now and that news would have been heard you. and `compile sdk 26`.
10. Just Bind Your `JobService` in manifest and use a single line permission of `receive_boot_complete`
11. Just schedule it ... And it will be started on every device in market from every manufacturer... even on `cold boot` and `hot boot`
12. It minimises a lot, lot and lot of code and `you can focus on actual tasks`.
13. Once task is finished you can `return false` to indicate task has been finished and it will end the JobService.

---

Why i am suggesting because i am `CTO` of a well-`UNKNOwn` company and has been experienced the problems caused by `foreground service` across the many types of android phone manufacturers... It is not the `Apple and ios` so we had to experienced it. Remain developer since past 18 years and i mostly codes today too... in all of the development projects and its development strategies are thought by me only.

> Correct me ... too... As you have not mentioned `what your tasks` and
>   `project` is related to... and what you exactly wants to be done in a
>   `foreground service and intent-service`... Let me know..., It would be my pleasure to help you. It is a general theoretical answer rather than what you wants.... But for giving you actual answer i will need exact your project scope..

Comment: I would like to thank you for addressing my issue. As per my project requirement(which I cannot disclose publically), I have to use foreground service and this service will trigger new Jobintentservice which sends metric data and this is not getting killed automatically(Intentservice used to do). As per your suggestion, If I use, *firebasejobscheduler* this issue will get rid off? Let me give a try. Thanks a ton again

Comment: Issue will be issue until there are programming and dependancies error/s... Just implementing "firebasejobscheduler" won't solve your problem... These are paradigms ...

Comment: Agree with that. As per doc, JobIntentService will act like intent service and job scheduler. IntentService which I used earlier will stop once the work is done, when I replaced with JobIntentService didn't stop in < android 7 and that drains the battery like hell. I can see those service in running services as well.

Comment: Why sticked with "JobIntentService" only...? Rather than, Service, or IntentService?  Or what made you to decide, i will use and will go with  "JobIntentService" only ..!!   Please Specify..

Comment: if we start intent service from background it will throw *Illegal state exception* due to Background execution limit

Comment: Background execution limit can be crossed with either foreground service or if you do not want a STICKY notification then one should use alarmmanager...  Again with this you can run long running tasks but not a FOREVER task. Again on evry reboot alarms sets are not remembered by system so need to handle it with database and on startup again set alarms...

Comment: forgot to mention JobIntentService is still in alpha

Answer (score 1):

**JobIntentService which acts like Intent Service is not getting stopped once the work is done**

The issue is in your extended class FixedJobIntentService dequeueWork method.

Try changing it to something like below

```
GenericWorkItem superValue = super.dequeueWork();
if (superValue != null) {
    return new FixedGenericWorkItem(superValue);
}
return null;
```

Looking at the JobIntentSerivce code, Work Items processor logic is below, i.e until there are no work items left in the queue all items are processed (i.e onHandleWork is called for each item)

```
    while ((work = dequeueWork()) != null) {
        if (DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "Processing next work: " + work);
        onHandleWork(work.getIntent());
        if (DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "Completing work: " + work);
        work.complete();
    }
```

Issue in your implementation is after processing the first work item, the super.dequeueWork() returns null, which you are not taking care of and just sending a new FixedGenericWorkItem object passing null value. You might observe that a null value is passed to your onHandleWork in your subsequent calls.

Hope this helps resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need this much of a code. Create a new Class MyJobIntentService and write this much of a code and call postData() to start your service.

```
public class MyJobIntentService extends JobIntentService {

public static void postData(Context context, String data) {
    final Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyJobIntentService.class);
    intent.setAction(INITIAL_ACTION);
    intent.putExtra(SAMPLE_ID, data);
    enqueueWork(context, MyJobIntentService.class, 1000, intent);
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Ln.d("Cancelled service");
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
    protected void onHandleWork(@NonNull Intent intent) {
        if (intent != null) {
            final SampleRequest sampleRequest = requests.get(intent.getAction());
            if (sampleRequest != null) {
                try {
                   // perform some networking operations
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Log.d("Error for intent ");
                }
                Log.i("send action ");
            } else {                
               Log.e("action not found for ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And make sure to add your service in manifest file

```
<service
            android:name="service.MyJobIntentService"
            android:exported="false"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />
```

Comment: Have you gone through this issue tracker? https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63622293

Comment: Yeah i have read it whole. But i am not facing any crash issue from my users. The only issue i am facing is, the service doesnt start if many call are made to it and its happening on OREO device

Comment: That is true. My app used to make multiple calls to send metrics and this crash is happening often. Have tested that the JobIntentService is stopped once the work is done in android 7 and below?

Comment: Based on the comments it sounds like this is not an valid answer, or it has not been tested? If that is the case it should be removed.